# Trim text in a string

Tags: python

Have `text` and `limit`. Need to write function `trim_text(text, limit)` that returns string. That function

a)deletes substrings from new string if that substring is overlapping limit (exeption for 1st substring ).

b)adds "..." at the end of string

c) there should be no punctuation or spaces before "..."

example:

```
trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 24)
```

gives back: `"Proin eget tortor risus."`

```
trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 6)
```

gives back: `"Pro..."`

my attempt

```
def trimmed_text(text, limit):
            return text[:limit].rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + '...' if len(text) >
```

limit else text

gives wrong output for the following calls:

```
trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 33)
trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 28)
trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but counts the space as a character, if you dont want that you can just trim the space!

```
def trim_text(text, limit):
    if len(text) > limit:
        newLen = limit - 3
        text = text[:newLen] + '...'
    return text

print trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 24)
print trim_text("Proin eget tortor risus.", 9)
```

Comment: `trim_text('Python is simple to use, but it is a real programming language.', 62)`  divides the last substring(

Comment: @serg_ka that output is correct. The length of the input string is 63, therefore it took the first 59 letters and append `...` to it, to make the new length 62

Comment: I tested it with what you said didnt work, and my method worked for those and your examples for the proper output. @serg_ka